# What is the best way to connect two methods of different objects?

Tags: php, oop

There are two objects:

```
$user = new user($user_id);
$product = new product($product_id);
```

User added product. I need call `$product` object to add new product, and `$user` to update his stats. These two actions are fully connected with each other. How should I call them?

I can see two ways

```
# 1) two separate functions 
$product->add_new($product_data);
$user->added_product(); 

# 2) calling static method in the end of the first
$product->add_new($product_data, $user->id);
function add_new($data, $user_id)
{
    ... // data processing

    user::added_product($user_id); // static 
}
```

What is the best for feature development - first way (implicitly call two connected functions), or second, with static function?
I don't like static method, but if the product was not added for some reason, user statistics should not be added. So there will be some if/else in the top level of the code, and this is no good (I want them to be inside class).
Or maybe there is other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably create a separate class for Statistics and use it like this:

```
$stats = new Statistics($user_id);
$stats->add_product($product_id);
```